# VS 2010 express -- identifier "fd_set" is undefined

Tags: visual-studio-2010, sdl

I am programming in Visual Studio 2010 for Windows.

I do not understand why it does not recognize the type `fd_set`.

Am I missing a header?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fd_set structure is defined in Winsock2.h, as per MS documentation. See here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/windows/desktop/ms737873%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: Thanks, I add #include "winsock2.h" in my proyect but got many errors in winsock2.h.
For example: 

error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int 

Error 1882 error C2556: 'int (__cdecl *DECLARE_STDCALL_P(protoent *))(const char *)' : overloaded function differs only by return type from 'int (__cdecl *DECLARE_STDCALL_P(protoent *))(int)'

Comment: I resolved!! With winsock2.h not found, but yes found with winsock.h and add WS2_32.lib

Thanks very much